# Zend Session not working on my friend's computer

Tags: zend-framework, zend-session

My friend and I are working on a project together. I recently added some Zend_Sessions to our project. NOw when he downloads the latest version of the code, the platform does not run for him any more.

He deleted the entire forlder, and committed again from scratch, and it still does not run! When he comments our the session declaration, everything works fine.

What is the problem?!

If I comment out this line $sessionCredentials = new Zend_Session_Namespace('credentials'); then everything works fine. Again, this exact same code runs fine on my computer!

Comment: The problem is that we can't see any code to tell what the problem is. Also enable php errors

Comment: I have narrowed it down to this : $sessionCredentials = new Zend_Session_Namespace('credentials'); If this is highlighted out, then it all works out fine.

Comment: Are sessions/cookies enabled in your computer. Does it give any errors? 
check if http://www.phoca.cz/documents/16-joomla/336-how-to-enable-displaying-php-errors-on-site is enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the chmod of the session directory specified in your php settings ?